# Noisy label as a semi supervised

Tags: machine-learning, semi-supervised-learning

Hi I was wondering if we can compare Noisy label problem to a semi supervised approach? Also are there any papers on learning with noisy labels?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Define what is considered a noisy label. Instance duplicates with different labels?

Comment: Duplicates with different labels that makes the class space overly fragmented

Comment: Yes this is possible. I've done this in one of [my papers](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231215001174). Preprint freely available [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.3144).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider it as a semi-supervised learning problem. I would treat instances that have no contradicting duplicates as labelled instances, and instances with contradictory duplicates as unlabeled instances. Then it becomes a classical semi-supervised learning problem.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI15/paper/viewFile/9366/9948
Here is a paper start with initial noisy label data.